# How can I have a database with thousands of tables with varying number of columns that are all of the same class in Django / SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, orm, sqlalchemy

I have financial statement data on thousands of different companies. Some of the companies have data only for 2019, but for some I have decade long data. Each company financial statement have its own table structured as follows with columns in bold:

**lineitem---2019---2018---2017**
2...............1000....800.....600
3206...........700....300....-200
56.................50....100.....100
200...........1200......90.....700

This structure is preferred over more of a flat file structure like lineitem-year-amount since one query gives me the correct structure of the output for a financial statement table. lineitem is a foreignkey linking to the primary key of a mapping table with over 10,000 records. 3206 can for example mean "Debt to credit instituions". I also have a companyIndex table which has the company ID, company name, and table name. I am able to get the data into the database and make queries using sqlite3 in python, but advanced queries is somewhat of a challenge at times, not to mention that it can take a lot of time and not be very readable. I like the potential of using ORM in Django or SQLAlchemy. The ORM in SQLAlchemy seems to want me to know the name of the table I am about to create and want me to know how many columns to create, but I don't know that since I have a script that parses a datadump in csv which includes the company ID and financial statement data for the number of years it has operated. Also, one year later I will have to update the table with one additional year of data.

I have been watching and reading tutorials Django and SQLAlchemy, but have not been able to try it out too much in practise due to this initial problem which is a prerequisite for succeding in my project. I have googled and googled, and checked stackoverflow for a solution, but not found any solved questions (which is really surprising since I always find the solution on here).

So how can I insert the data using Django/SQLAlchemy given the structure I plan to have it fit into? How can I have the selected table(s) (based on company ID or company name) be an object(s) in ORM just like any other object allowing me the select the data I want at the granularity level I want?
Ideally there is a solution to this in Django, but since I haven't found anything I suspect there is not or that how I have structured the database is insanity.

Comment: ...and by the way, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: As you are new here, take your time to read the help center, Specially [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Take into account that info for future questions. I see no problem in your question but you will understand after reading the help, that by the rules it is a bit borderline. Questions styled very differently from the rules may get downvoted by some.

Comment: By borderline I just meant most of the questions here show a small code snippet you tried and does not work, and ask for help in making it work. Nothing more serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find a solution because there is none.
You are mixing the input data format with the table schema.

You establish an initial database table schema and then add data as rows to the tables.
You never touch the database table columns again, unless you decide that the schema has to be altered to support different, usually additional functionality in the application, because for example, at a certain point in the application lifetime, new attributes become required for data. Not because there is more data, wich simply translates to new data rows in one or more tables.

So first you decide about a proper schema for database tables, based on the data records you will be reading or importing from somewhere.

Then you make sure the database is normalized until 3rd normal form.
You really have to understand [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Haven't read it, just skimmed over but I assume it is correct. This is fundamental database knowledge you cannot escape. After learning it right and with practice it becomes second nature and you will apply the rules without even noticing.

Then your problems will vanish, and you can do what you want with whatever relational database or ORM you want to use.

The only remaining problem is that input data needs validation, and sometimes it is not given to us in the proper form. So the program, or an initial import procedure, or further data import operations, may need to give data some massaging before writing the proper data rows into the existing tables.

Comment: Thank you, progmatico. In order to satisfy the requirements for 3rd normal form (including no insertion, deletion, update anomalies) I think I have to make my company tables into one single table **lineitem (foreignKey) - companyID (foreignKey) - type  -year - amount** (type would represent statutory/consolidated, about 10% have both).  With about 1m companies, average 10yrs, average lineitems 50. 1m x 10 x 50 x110% equals 550 million rows. (1) I dont know if that is possible, (2) if possible I am assuming the performance would be horrible as well. Do you have some thoughts on how to approach?

Comment: I have actually bought a book on database design (Beginning Database Design Solutions by Rod Stephens), so I definitely understand that there is some significance in understanding these concepts! I just have to get on with my reading - I guess I am trying to run before I walk. Any ideas as to what to read up on for my particular problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: Having that book looks  great for what you need. Definitely read p27, then ch3, then p106 to p117 in ch5 and ch5 p113 to p150, and you should be on your way to a good table and relation schema.

Comment: Do not assume something about performance without real world experience. Databases are probably the best tool you have to get optimal performance in processing data records. Forget performance worries until you can test with real data and real data volumes.

Comment: Indexing and later optimizations can make miracles, just do not store blobs in it, store paths to filenames if you need to store that kind of thing.

Comment: Cannot comment on your schema but lineitem looks like a poor (unreadable) name for your table unless it was about say lines in  an invoice. What is a lineitem? That is the name for the thing.

Comment: What pops up to my eyes is that you can't have years in their own columns. To not store lots of repeated year values in a table, operational years are probably a table by themselves with other tables using foreign keys.

Comment: Short for financial statement line item - it holds the pk value of the mapping table which holds the full name of line item including important information about said line item.  Probably have some way to go on naming conventions as well ;)

Comment: naming conventions are important for clarity when writing queries. You should know what you are doing but remember schemas can get big in the long run, so choose perfectly clear names. Text editors can complete longer names for you. Use the same criteria as for variable names in code.